# mouse/cursor is disappearing after sleep

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, suspend, logout

I've got a problem where my mouse cursor keeps disappearing when my session times out. I log back in and it's invisible, though I can still move it around the screen and click things. I'm in Lubuntu 15.04 and I've tried...

1. reading as many answered questions as I can find
2. installing gdm (says something is in use by another program and can't be installed)
3. Using unclutter to switch mouse on and off (can't find a command that toggles the mouse
4. Switching into the login screen and back (ctr-alt-f2 and ctr-alt-f7)

System reboot is the only solution I've found and it's quite onerous. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: I would first install a supported release of Ubuntu, such as 14.04, 15.10 or 16.04, which is going to be released some time on the 21st (tomorrow/today).

Answer (score 5):

I have stumbled on this odd bug with a Lubuntu 16 on an Acer Aspire D250. Searching for a fix I found this workaround: pressing `Ctrl-Alt-F1` and then `Ctrl-Alt-F7` makes the cursor reappear. Works on my system.

Comment: Yes, it works for me too, but is there a short script or command that could bring back the cursor without doing all this?

Answer (score 3):

I found this looking for the solution to the same problem (this is still happening on Xubuntu 16.04, so updating to a supported release does not solve this issue). I don't know how to prevent this, but I can reliably recover the mouse cursor without rebooting. Open the display manager (Super + P) and make any change you want (change the screen resolution, then change it back. This brings the pointer back whenever a change like this is made. I took this one step further : you can use xrandr for this and map this to a keyboard shortcut. For my laptop I ended up setting Ctrl+Alt+Left arrow to run

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left
```

and then Ctrl+Alt+Down runs

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate normal
```

so I can quickly rotate left then back to normal and bring the cursor back very easily. Still annoying, but easily overcome.

Comment: For me, it is the use of `Xrandr` that made the cursor disappear in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

I have one installation of 14.04 with exactly this behaviour. Don't know why, but workaround as follows.

1. Bring up a terminal, Ctrl+Alt+t
2. Hit return in the terminal window and the mouse pointer reappears.

Comment: while in the terminal, typing `xrefresh` also seems to help

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue (Lubuntu 16.04), and found an answer that worked [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321778&p=13520064#post13520064).

### The Fix:

I added [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && sudo apt-get update
```

And then updated `xserver-xorg-video-intel` with:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

This seems to have fixed it for me.

#### Alternative:

According to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604/comments/232), this was fixed in `xserver-xorg-video-intel - 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1.1`, so you might find that simply updating the package with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel` works. You can see which packages will be installed with the following command:

```
  ~ $ sudo apt-cache madison xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel | 2:2.99.917+git1609021930.ebc066~gd~x | http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-video-intel | 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1.1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-video-intel | 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```